# Iterate over Rows in Pandas Dataframe keeping first 2 Rows Fixed

Tags: python, pandas

[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9laC.png)

I have a DataFrame as Shown above.Is there any way where I can create a new dataframe everytime having row index `[0,1,2], [0,1,3],[0,1,4]` means keeping the first 2 rows of the dataframe fixed (in this case index 0 and 1) and including the next one row in the fixed rows.

The Output should be having DataFrame with Rows `[0,1,2], [0,1,3],[0,1,4]` and so on in Python.

Comment: Don't post images of data, provide data in text so others can easily copy it

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['AA','BB','CC','DD','EE'], 'B': ['AA', 'AA', 'BB','BB','BB'], 'C': ['CC', 'CC', 'DD', 'DD', 'DD']})

def make_new_df(row_to_keep, orig_df):
    new_df=pd.DataFrame(columns=list(orig_df))
    new_df.loc[0]=orig_df.loc[0]
    new_df.loc[1]=orig_df.loc[1]
    new_df.loc[2]=orig_df.loc[row_to_keep]
    return new_df
```

Where you call new_df with the row index that you want to keep as the parameter, and the original dataframe you want to get the rows from.

Answer (score 0):

As cleared from the comment, that you want a new `dataframe` for each row in addition to the first two rows, do:

```
new_df_dict = {}
for i in range(2, len(df)):
    new_df_dict[i] = df.iloc[[0, 1, i], :]
```

After that you will have in `new_df_dict` a dictionary of all the new `dataframes`, as the key of the dictionary is the number of the new row.

Comment: I want as a Separate Dataframe each time as mentioned with first two rows always in the dataframe with next rows added to these two rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reindex:

```
df1=df.reindex[0,1,2]
df2=df.reindex[0,1,3]
etc.
```

If you want to use slices:

```
df10=df.reindex( np.r_[0,1,10:len(df)] )
```